# I am not able to bind the API JSON response to angular typescript class

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-httpclient, webapi

I am new to angular, trying to call web API from angular. I am facing a very different problem that the response is getting empty array.
Here, I have added my service.ts code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GroupResult } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


class TodoListModel{
  id?:number | null;
  itemName!:String;
  dueDate!:Date;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {


  public initDueTime: Date = new Date(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
  public hourlyTodos: ToDo[] | GroupResult[] =[];
  
  todos:ToDo[] = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  readonly rootUrl=`https://localhost:44353/api`;
  private todoListModel: TodoListModel[] | JSON=[];
  
  refreshList(){
     //this.http.get(this.rootUrl+"/todos").toPromise().then(res=>this.todoListModel=res as TodoListModel[]);
     this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`).pipe(
       map((data: TodoListModel[])=>{
         return data;
       }),
       catchError(error=>{
         return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
       })
     )
     console.log(this.todoListModel);
  }
}

export interface ToDo{
  item:string;
  due:Date;
  hour:number;
}
```

There's one error that is related to animations, that should not bother.

And my console looks like this:
empty array:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't ask a specific question, but based on your tittle, you just should need this (map is not needed):

```
refreshList(){
   this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`)
   .pipe(
       catchError(error=>{
         return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
       })
     )
   .subscribe( (res:TodoListModel[]) => {
                         this.todoListModel = res;
                         console.log(this.todoListModel);
   });
    
  }
```

I rather deal errors in this way, but it's not needed:

```
refreshList(){
   this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`)
   .subscribe( 
      (res:TodoListModel[]) => {
         this.todoListModel = res;
         console.log(this.todoListModel);
      },
      (error) => throwError(`Something's wrong`);
    );
}
```

Comment: refreshList(){
    this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`)
    .pipe(
        catchError(error=>{
          return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
        })
      )
    .subscribe( (res:TodoListModel[]) => {
                          this.todoListModel = res;
                          console.log(this.todoListModel);
    });
     console.log(this.todoListModel);
  }
}
console log inside subscribe function works but not outside, how's that possible?

Comment: Because you get the data asynchronously, and if you left the console.log() outside, when the execution gets to console.log(), it doesn't have data yet. ( if it is outside subscibe, you get to it before todoListModel makes the assignment (this.todoListModel = res;)

Comment: `refreshList(){
    this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`)
    .pipe(
        catchError(error=>{
          return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
        })
      )
    .subscribe( (res:TodoListModel[]) => {
                          this.todoListModel = res;
                          console.log(this.todoListModel);
    });
     console.log(this.todoListModel);
  }
}`
here in this code snippet, **console.log(this.todoListModel)** is returning an empty array when outside subscribe method. why? Please elaborate on the problem and give me the solution.

Comment: I already told you the reason: You think that console.log() outside the subscribe is running at the end, after the subscribe, but it doesn't, because you are working wiht async methods. Check by yourself: put console.log("1"); inside the subscribe, and console.log("2"); outside (at the end).Run the code and your are gona see in the console, first "2" and then "1".    I hope this helps you to understand the why.

Comment: How can I not async methods that is have sync methods?

Comment: Please upvote my question

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you need to alter your pipe/map by assigning the data(data: TodoListModel[]) to this.todoListModel as below:

```
this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`).pipe(
  map((data: TodoListModel[])=>{
    this.todoListModel = data;
  }), catchError(error=>{
    return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
  }) 
)
```

I have modified the code which you have mentioned:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GroupResult } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


class TodoListModel{
  id?:number | null;
  itemName!:String;
  dueDate!:Date;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {


  public initDueTime: Date = new Date(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
  public hourlyTodos: ToDo[] | GroupResult[] =[];
  
  todos:ToDo[] = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  readonly rootUrl=`https://localhost:44353/api`;
  private todoListModel: TodoListModel[] | JSON=[];
  
  refreshList(){
     this.http.get<TodoListModel[]>(this.rootUrl+`/todos`).pipe(
       map((data: TodoListModel[])=>{
         this.todoListModel = data;
       }),
       catchError(error=>{
         return throwError(`Something's wrong`);
       })
     )
     console.log(this.todoListModel);
  }
}

export interface ToDo{
  item:string;
  due:Date;
  hour:number;
}
```